# Removing last two elements from a list in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I need to remove the last two elements from a list in common list, but I can remove only one. What's the way?

```
(defun my-butlast (list)
        (loop for l on list
              while (rest l)
              collect (first l)))
```

Comment: `while (rest (rest l))`?

Comment: @melpomene i was trying different methods to implement it

Comment: `(remove-if #'atom '(1 2 3 (1 2 3 4) 5) :count 2 :from-end t)` => `(1 2 (1 2 3 4))`.

Comment: @jkiiski could you please integrate it in the a function.plz MyList = ( A B C D)..i am trying to write a function to remove C D from the list. so that it becomes Mylist = (A B)

Comment: `(subseq list :start 0 :end (- (length list) 2))`  - this would be my goto solution

Comment: Why not just **(butlast '(1 2 3 4) 2) ⇒ (1 2)**?  The function takes a second argument that specifies how many arguments to drop.

Comment: How about change `l` to `(f nil . rest)` then change `(rest l)` to `rest` and `(first l)` to `f`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: *reverse, pop, pop, reverse* ;-) <sup>**1**</sup>

More efficiently, the following works too:

```
(let ((list '(a b c d)))
  (loop 
    for x in list
    for y in (cddr list)
    collect x))
```

This can also be written, for some arbitrary L and N:

```
(mapcar #'values L (nthcdr N L))
```

It works because iteration over multiple lists is bounded by the shortest one. What matters here is the length of the second list (we don't care about its values), which is the length of the original list minus N, which must be a [non-negative integer](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nthcdr.htm). Notice that `NTHCDR` conveniently works with sizes greater than the length of the list given in argument.

With the second example, I use the [`VALUES`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_values.htm) function as a generalized identity function; [`MAPCAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) only uses the primary value of the computed values, so this works as desired.
The behavior is consistent with the actual [`BUTLAST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_butlas.htm)<sup>**2**</sup> function, which returns `nil` for N larger than the number of elements in the list. The actual `BUTLAST` function can also deal with improper (dotted) lists, but the above version cannot.

---

**1.** `(alexandria:compose #'nreverse #'cddr #'reverse)`

**2.** `BUTLAST` is specified as being equivalent to `(ldiff list (last list n))`. I completely forgot about the existence of [`LDIFF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ldiffc.htm) !

Comment: Would have worked with pain `cddr` as well for this case. How this is written though you can make it general function that takes the amount to shop off as an argument.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, it makes more sense to use CDDR in the example and generalize afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: There's no need for this.  **butlast** exists in the standard, and takes an optional second argument that specifies how many elements to exclude.  I've added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45243345/1281433).

Answer (score 4):

There's a function in the standard for this: [**butlast**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_butlas.htm), or if you're willing to modify the input list, **[nbutlast](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_butlas.htm)**.

> butlast returns a copy of list from which the last n conses have been omitted. If n is not supplied, its value is 1. If there are fewer than n conses in list, nil is returned and, in the case of nbutlast, list is not modified.
>
> nbutlast is like butlast, but nbutlast may modify list. It changes the cdr of the cons n+1 from the end of the list to nil.

Examples:

```
CL-USER> (butlast '(1 2 3 4 5) 2)
(1 2 3)
CL-USER> (nbutlast (list 6 7 8 9 10) 2)
(6 7 8)
```

The fact that you called your function **my-butlast** suggests that you might know about this function, but you didn't mention wanting to not use this function, so I assume it's still fair game.  Wrapping it up is easy:

```
CL-USER> (defun my-butlast (list)
           (butlast list 2))
MY-BUTLAST
CL-USER> (my-butlast (list 1 2 3 4))
(1 2)
```